# Can't access WAMP 3 Server publicly

Tags: apache, http, webserver, wamp, portforwarding

I've downloaded and freshly installed wamp 3 several times now because i cannot get it  public for the life of me.
I have a working Port Forward for Port 8080 and opened it  for UDP/TCP in my Firewall.
I set  my local IP Address to 192.168.0.120
My httpd-vhost.conf looks like this:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From what i understand, i do not have to edit httpd.conf whatsoever when i use the Virtual server.
I Can access it locally, with 192.168.0.120:8080 on my phone, but It's not seen on https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ or when usuing my DDNS/Public IP (Tried Public IP with my mobile data so i can simulate external  access)
What is left   to do?

Comment: So by what address or name do you try to reach that server from an external location?

Comment: http://www.whatsmyip.org/ Your IP Address is X.X.X.X <- keeping this a secret
I tried  connecting with both X.X.X.X
 and X.X.X.X:8080
of course, i didn't write X.X.X.X  (not that much of an  idiot)

Comment: I understand this such that you are using the external IP address of your router? That is fine as long as that virtual host is the fallback host of your http server, so the only or the first defined host. If that does not work, then you have a routing issue. Most likely the port forwarding does not work or there is another firewall blocking the requests. Note that you have at least two firewalls you need to open: on your router and on the system the http server is operated on.

Comment: Do you mean by this that it has to be the only virtual host that i have?
If yes, then that's not my issue, i have only editet the standart  localhost virtual server, not made any new  ones. I'll see if i find any issues with the port forward.

Comment: OK, i  found the Problem, my Port forward had "Disabled" checked for some reason... Thank you very much!